# Do the following ideals generate the polynomial ring $K[x,y,z]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, polynomial-rings

> $I=(x-y^2z,x+y^2z)$ and $I=(x^2y,y^3z,xyz)$ generate $K[x,y,z]$. If not, find two that do. ($K$ is a field and $I$ is an ideal).

Now, my question might really be trivial but here it goes:
I know that if they would generate it this would imply that the elements of K[x,y,z] could be written as linear combinations of the elements of the Ideals, but how can I know this? I mean K[x,y,z] has infinitely many elements how do I check or understand that an Ideal does indeed generate them all. And the same problem goes when the ideal is not given and I have to find it. How can I be sure that it is indeed the correct Ideal.

I am a total beginner in Algebra and I have always problems with this sort of questions regarding generating ideals. People seem to see it right away and I don't know if there is any way which I am not aware of.

Thanks very much for any sort of help.

Comment: An ideal $I$ is equal to the whole ring if and only if $I$ contains the element $1$. Here's a proof: Suppose the ideal is equal to the whole ring. Well then it definitely contains $1$. On the other hand, suppose the ideal contains $1$ and try to show the ideal is the whole ring. Let $r \in R$ and try to show $r \in I$. Remember that ideals are closed under multiplication by ring elements. So $1 \in I$ implies $r \cdot 1 \in I$. So $r \in I$, as desired. So--to see if an ideal is the whole ring or not, just check to see if it contains $1$.

Comment: @beanshadow i am not sure how i could get 1 as a combination of the elements of these ideals, so it means that they are not the whole ring?

Comment: @Annalisa you suggest trying to write $1 = fx + gy$. Well, let's insist $f$ and $g$ are actually elements of the polynomial ring $K[x,y,z]$. Note that your try with $\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't work because $\frac{1}{x}$ isn't a polynomial. Once you insist that $f,g$ are polynomials, to find a problem, ask: "what's the degree of either side of $1 = fx+gy?$"